# How to set up developing Django, JavaScript with Docker and static files? To get real time web page changes

Tags: django, docker, nginx, npm, django-staticfiles

Currently I have Docker container. The process with main.js:

0. npm renders main.js and store it in static folder (out of the docker container)
1. Docker compose and docker file collects static files in static-volume, including main.js
2. Nginx serves main.js from static-volume

But when I make changes to the source code, I can see the results only after restarting container and "docker volume prune" command.

I want to have changes of the web page right after code is changed. And what is the best practise in this scenario?

Comment: Did u find a way?

Comment: A guy from Django community in Discord advised me to have separate projects, one for developing and one for Docker.